# CSS Masonry Formatting Issue

Tags: html, css

I have my website in which I have a masonry layout on my photo pages. It's supposed to look like this: [image: Masonry Layout Example]

However, for some reason, it looks like this:
[image: Masonry problem]

It looks like the "Sarah Baker" box right below the "Megan Bradley" box is one pixel larger than the "Ryan Soeder" box. I think that's the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

So my problem is that there's all that white space below the "Sarah Baker" box when there shouldn't be.

I've tried messing with margins in the CSS, but nothing has come from that. I don't use any JS or jQuery plugin for the layout. It's all done through the CSS.

The HTML for this section looks like this:

```
    <section id="portfolio" class="c zoomy">
        <div class="a">
                <article>
                    <header>
                    <h3>Megan Bradley</h3>
                    <p>Elegance and sass</p>
                    <p class="link"><a href="megan-bradley.html">View</a></p>
                </header>
                <figure><img src="images/portfolio/mains/megan-main.jpg" alt="Megan Bradley's Senior Photos" width="1440" height="960"></figure>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <header>
                    <h3>Sarah Baker</h3>
                    <p>Fun in the sun</p>
                    <p class="link"><a href="sarah-baker.html">View</a></p>
                </header>
                <figure><img src="images/portfolio/mains/sarah-main.jpg" alt="Sarah Baker's Senior Photos" width="1440" height="960"></figure>
                </article>
            </div>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h3>Ryan Soeder</h3>
                    <p>The Bow Tie Man</p>
                    <p class="link"><a href="ryan-soeder.html">View</a></p>
                </header>
                <figure><img src="images/portfolio/mains/ryan-main.jpg" alt="Ryan Soeder's Senior Photos" width="1440" height="960"></figure>
            </article>
            <article class="a">
                <header>
                    <h3>Becky Smith</h3>
                    <p>Curly hair, don't care</p>
                    <p class="link"><a href="becky-smith.html">View</a></p>
                </header>
                <figure><img src="images/portfolio/mains/becky-main(long).jpg" alt="Becky Smith's Senior Photos" width="1440" height="1920"></figure>
            </article>
            <article class="a">
                <header>
                    <h3>Bri</h3>
                    <p>Fierce</p>
                    <p class="link"><a href="bri-.html">View</a></p>
                </header>
                <figure><img src="images/portfolio/mains/bri-main(long).jpg" alt="Becky Smith's Senior Photos" width="1440" height="1920"></figure>
            </article>
            <div class="a">
                <article>
                    <header>
                    <h3>Megan Bradley</h3>
                    <p>Elegance and sass</p>
                    <p class="link"><a href="megan-bradley.html">View</a></p>
                </header>
                <figure><img src="images/portfolio/mains/megan-main.jpg" alt="Megan Bradley's Senior Photos" width="1440" height="960"></figure>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div class="a">
                <article>
                    <header>
                    <h3>Sarah Baker</h3>
                    <p>Fun in the sun</p>
                    <p class="link"><a href="sarah-baker.html">View</a></p>
                </header>
                <figure><img src="images/portfolio/mains/sarah-main.jpg" alt="Sarah Baker's Senior Photos" width="1440" height="960"></figure>
                </article>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#portfolio, #portfolio > div {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
}

#portfolio article {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#portfolio article.hidden, #portfolio.c > div.hidden {
    position: absolute;
}

#portfolio header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 100px;
    z-index: 4;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -600px;
    padding: 0 0 7px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#portfolio h1, #portfolio h2, #portfolio h3 {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 2.3em;
}

#portfolio h1, #portfolio h2, #portfolio h3 {
    transform: translateY(21px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(21px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(21px);
    -o-transform: translateY(21px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(21px);
}

#portfolio article:hover h1, #portfolio article:hover h2, #portfolio article:hover h3 {
    transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
}

#portfolio article p {
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1;
}

#portfolio article p {
    transform: scale(0,0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0,0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0,0);
    -o-transform: scale(0,0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0,0);
}

#portfolio article:hover p {
    transform: scale(1,1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    -o-transform: scale(1,1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1,1);
}

#portfolio header > .fit-a {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 70px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -35px;
}

#portfolio article:hover header > .fit-a {
    background: #fff;
}

#portfolio header > .link {
    position: absolute;
    left: -3000em;
    top: -3000em;
}

#portfolio figure {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0;
}

#portfolio figure img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

#portfolio video {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    border-width: 0;
    background: #000;
    image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.js #portfolio video + figure {
    position: absolute;
    left: -3000em;
    top: -3000em;
}

#portfolio article > .fit-a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,189,188,.5);
    opacity: 0;
}

.lt-ie9 #portfolio article:hover > .fit-a {
    background: transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#3acbc7,endColorstr=#3acbc7);
    zoom: 1;
}

#portfolio article:hover .fit-a {
    opacity: 1;
}

#portfolio a {
    color: #fff;
}

#portfolio article > .link {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#portfolio article > .link a {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-indent: -3000em;
}

#portfolio .link-b {
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    padding: 50px 0 0;
}

#portfolio.a {
}

#portfolio.a video, #portfolio.b video, #portfolio.c video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

#portfolio.a article {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
}

#portfolio.a header, #portfolio.b header, #portfolio.c header {
    left: 3%;
    bottom: 54px;
    width: 94%;
    margin: 0;
}

.js #portfolio.a video + figure, .js #portfolio.b video + figure, .js #portfolio.c video + figure {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#portfolio.b {
}

#portfolio.b article {
    float: left;
    margin 0 auto; width: 33.33333%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px;
}

#portfolio.c {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

#portfolio.c > div {
    float: left;
    height: 50%;
    border-radius: 0;
}

#portfolio.c article {
    overflow: visible;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#portfolio.c article {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#portfolio.c article:after, #portfolio.c article:before, #portfolio.c > div:before, #portfolio.c > div:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #fff;
}

#portfolio.c article:before, #portfolio.c > div:before {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

#portfolio.c article:after, #portfolio.c > div:after {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
}

#portfolio.c article figure > *, #portfolio.c article figure, #portfolio.c article > .fit-a, #portfolio.c video {
    border-radius: 0;
    /*margin: none !important;*/
}

#portfolio.c > .a {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

#portfolio.c > .b {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333%;
}

#portfolio.c > .a article, #portfolio.c > .b article {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes please to the CSS

Comment: @Jay I updated the format in the original post. If you can't see it, here's the link to the file: [CSS File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-FAI96lYzLoM3NWd1F4V2VvNDA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm sorry but that's far too much information to dig through.. Can you replicate the problem in a fiddle? Doesn't need to be the entire page. Just the part that's misbehaving.

Comment: @Jay Updated. These are all the places I could see the problem being.